# PHP Add a new array key based on an existing keys values

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add a new array key and value to an existing array based on a value in the array? The below is just a part of the array. The original has some 1000+ keys.

The key `Date` will always be present. The values before `Date` are not fixed and will change.

Here's the array I have:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Date 
[1] => Name
[2] => Other Data
[3] => More Data
[4] => Date 
[5] => Name
[7] => Other Data
[8] => Date 
[9] => Name
[10] => Other Data
 )
```

I'd like to add a new key before every `Date` in the array, except the first one. How is this possible to do?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Date 
[1] => Name
[2] => Other Data
[3] => More Data
[*] => // New data here
[4] => Date 
[5] => Name
[7] => Other Data
[*] => // New data here
[8] => Date 
[9] => Name
[10] => Other Data
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its working.

```
<?php 
 $array1 = array('Date','Name','Other Data','More Data','Date','Name','Other Data','Date','Name','Other Data');
 $array2 = array();

 foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    if($k != 0 && $array1[$k] == "Date") {
        $array2['d'.($k+1)] = " // New Date";
    }
    $array2[] = $v;
 }
?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Date
    [1] => Name
    [2] => Other Data
    [3] => More Data
    [d5] =>  // New Date
    [4] => Date
    [5] => Name
    [6] => Other Data
    [d8] =>  // New Date
    [7] => Date
    [8] => Name
    [9] => Other Data
)
```

You can change **key** or **value** for you requirement.

```
"d1" as new key
"// New Date" as new value
```